# Limit string array output to first 500 characters

Tags: powershell, svn, text

I'm using Subversion and using `svn help status` a lot. It spits out a lot of text. How can I tell PowerShell to only display the first 500 characters of the entire output (not of each line)?

The following limits to the first 500 lines not characters.

```
 $ svn help status | select -first 500
```

That's because `(svn help status).GetType()` is an array of strings. Do I need to write something funky to count the characters in each line, or is this a built in way to do this?

Comment: Is your title wrong or your question. Do you want first 500 characters or 5 ( not that it matters solutions are tailored for it.) Also do you only want the first X characters on each line or the first X characters of the whole output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First using -join to turn the array of strings into one single string (`n is the newline character to preserve lines), then selecting the first 500 characters with [0..499] and finally joining these again (otherwise each character is output on a separate line):

```
((svn help status) -join "`n")[0..499] -join ''
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Filter prune ([int]$count) {$_[0..($count-1)] -join '' }

svn help status | prune 5
```

That will be slower than the `substring()` method, but it won't throw errors if it hits a short string.

Comment: I'm afraid errors are flying everywhere. `Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.` Upvote for effort, though.

Comment: I'm guessing some of those lines have less than $count characters in them.  Substring() complains about that.  I'll use a different method.

Comment: Doesn't work correctly. It gives the first 6 characters of each line.

Comment: It needs to have $count decremented because of the 0 based indexing.  I fixed that in the answer, but am tempted to just delete it and forget the whole thing.